# How to differentiate firebase authenitcated users in multiple apps in same firebase project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have one project based on firebase in which i have multiple apps having same code but white labeled data.
All users are authenticated by firebase authentication.
Now the Problem is when one authenticated used tries to login in the one white label app it logged in sucessfully but when same users who is not registered in another white labeled app also  logged in as same authentication process because of one authentication for all apps in same project in firebase.
so I want to know how to differentiate the users in same firebase project with multiple apps ?
sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Claims to track which user have access to which apps. Note that this require you to use Cloud Functions
Custom Claims documents: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Cloud Functions sample code:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {whiteLabelApp1: true}).then(() => {//do something here if you want});
```

And for client code, just refer to the docs